# VSTO PowerPoint Add-in: Right way to get tab positions from TabStops2

Tags: c#, ms-office, vsto, powerpoint, office-interop

*Sorry my English :)*

Our team develop VSTO Add-in for PowerPoint. I have `myTextRange2.ParagraphFormat.TabStops` which contains two different positions (62,83142 and 77,99763) and I am confused because

1) If I execute:

```
TextRange2 myTextRange2; // method parameter  
var tabPosition1 = myTextRange2.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Item(1).Position;
var tabPosition2 = myTextRange2.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Item(2).Position;
```

`tabPosition1` and `tabPosition2` have same value 62,83142

2) If I execute:

```
TextRange2 myTextRange2; // method parameter  
var tabPosition2 = myTextRange2.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Item(2).Position;
var tabPosition1 = myTextRange2.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Item(1).Position;
```

`tabPosition1` and `tabPosition2` have same value 77,99763

What is happened? What I do not understand? How properly to get those two different position values?

Comment: I cannot repro the problem. But  without your complete code it is hard to say what is causing it on your end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also discussed this problem on [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5163adbf-81ef-4c49-ae9a-0b56a7609c01/right-way-to-get-tab-positions-from-tabstops2?forum=vsto). Solution is

```
TextRange2 myTextRange2; // method parameter                    
float tabPosition1 = myTextRange2.get_Paragraphs().ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Item(1).Position;
float tabPosition2 = myTextRange2.get_Paragraphs().ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Item(2).Position;
```